# MySQL: How to join when a particular type of record isn't in another table

Tags: mysql, outer-join

My brain is turning to mush over this one, but I suspect there's an easy answer.

I have a table of theatre shows and I also have a table of reviews of those shows. The reviews have a flag to signify whether the review is in-house or an audience review, i.e. 1 for in-house, 0 for audience.

Now, what I want to do is return all shows that don't have an in-house review. I tried the following, but no results (obviously because I'm conflicting r.id is NULL and r.author = 1)

```
     SELECT s.title FROM shows s LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews r ON s.id = r.showid WHERE r.id is NULL AND r.author = 1
```

If I take off the r.author = 1 then I get results, but false positives if there's an audience review.

Answer (score 2):

Transfer `r.author = 1` in the `ON` clause to filter table `reviews` first before joining with `shows`.

```
SELECT s.title 
FROM   shows s 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews r 
          ON s.id = r.showid AND 
             r.author = 1
WHERE  r.showid is NULL
```

The difference between `ON` and `WHERE` is that `ON` filters the rows from a specific table before joining on the other table while `WHERE` filters the result after the tables has been joined.